# How to parse text file to load arrays in batch script

Tags: arrays, windows, parsing, batch-file

If I have this text file keys.txt:

```
key1=val 1
key2=val 2
key3=val 3
```

I can use this script to load this script to load the values:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("keys.txt") do (
    set "%%~I=%%~J"
)

set key
```

The output is:

```
key1=val 1
key2=val 2
key3=val 3
```

However, I'm trying to load the following list values with known names into arrays in batch script:

```
;files array
files=filename1
files=filename2
...
files=filename_n
;folders array 
folders=foldername1
folders=foldername2
... 
folders=foldername_n
;sources array 
sources=value1
sources=vakue2
... 
sources=vakue_n
;other key value pairs
do_copy=yes
messagePromot=Are you sure?
```

I want the batch script to create 3 arrays in batch script by parsing the text file above. The result arrays will be:

```
files[0]=filename1
files[1]=filename2
...
files[n]=filename_n

folders[0]=foldername1
folders[1]=foldername2
...
folders[n]=foldername_n

sources[0]=value1
sources[1]=value2
...
sources[n]=value_n

do_copy=yes
messagePrompt=Are you sure?
```

Suppose the array variables are known or predictable, the how I can write the batch script to parse such text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q77561414.txt"

:: remove variables starting count_
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set count_ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%c" neq "" (
  IF DEFINED count_%%b (SET /a count_%%b+=1) ELSE (SET /a count_%%b=0)
  SET "%%b[!count_%%b!]=%%c"
 )
)
SET count
SET |FIND "["

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

You would need to change the value assigned to `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q77561414.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Note use of [DELAYEDEXPANSION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947) to access the values of the `count` variables.

You haven't said what to do with `other key value pairs`, so I've just processed them...

`count`s start at 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! The other key values should be used to create variable with the name and value as usual. I'll check your solution.

Comment: I am very grateful and words cannot express my appreciation. The solution worked immediately. After finalizing it, I will modify it to meet my needs and add another answer.

Comment: I posted my answer. I will create another question to solve this problem: How to find out the unique names of the newly created variables?

Comment: I appreciate your help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77979231/4180447.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Magoo for providing the answer. In this answer, I will modify it to meet my needs:

the input file is:

```
; Define list of files
files_arr=filename1.txt
files_arr=filename2.dat
files_arr=filename3.cfg
; Define list of folders 
folders_arr=c:\folder1
folders_arr=c:\folder2
folders_arr=c:\folder3
; Define list of users
users_arr=user name 1
users_arr=user name 2
users_arr=user name 3
users_arr=user name 4
; Define list of sources
sources_arr=source value 1
sources_arr=source value 2
sources_arr=source value 3
; Define normal variables
do_copy_file=yes
delete_after_copy=no
```

The script:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "configfile=.\testconfigfile.txt"

:: remove variables starting count_
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set count_ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%b IN ("%configfile%") DO (
 IF "%%c" neq "" (
  set keyname=%%b
  echo Key Name = !keyname!
  if "!keyname:~-4!"=="_arr" (
    IF DEFINED count_%%b (SET /a count_%%b+=1) ELSE (SET /a count_%%b=0)
    SET "!keyname![!count_%%b!]=%%c"
  ) else (
    SET "!keyname!=%%c"
  )
 )
)
SET count
SET |FIND "["
SET do_
SET delete_

GOTO :EOF
```

I could not figure out how to display only the variables that were created in the current batch script. I hope I can get help with that.