# How to identify the list of unique variable names that are parsed from text file using batch script

Tags: arrays, windows, parsing, batch-file

Thanks to @Magoo for helping me write the script to parse the text file. Reference here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77561672/4180447

I have the following text file with array values and key values:

```
; Define list of files
files_arr=filename1.txt
files_arr=filename2.dat
files_arr=filename3.cfg
; Define list of folders 
folders_arr=c:\folder1
folders_arr=c:\folder2
folders_arr=c:\folder3
; Define list of users
users_arr=user name 1
users_arr=user name 2
users_arr=user name 3
users_arr=user name 4
; Define list of sources
sources_arr=source value 1
sources_arr=source value 2
sources_arr=source value 3
; Define normal variables
do_copy_file=yes
delete_after_copy=no
```

The following batch script will parse the key/value pairs and load arrays and key values accordingly to array variables and normal variables:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "configfile=.\testconfigfile.txt"

:: remove variables starting count_
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set count_ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%b IN ("%configfile%") DO (
 IF "%%c" neq "" (
  set keyname=%%b
  echo Key Name = !keyname!
  if "!keyname:~-4!"=="_arr" (
    IF DEFINED count_%%b (SET /a count_%%b+=1) ELSE (SET /a count_%%b=0)
    SET "!keyname![!count_%%b!]=%%c"
  ) else (
    SET "!keyname!=%%c"
  )
 )
)
:: Display the values of the count variables
SET count
:: Display the values of the array variables
SET |FIND "["
:: display the values of the normal variables from the text file
SET do_
SET delete_

GOTO :EOF
```

How I can create a list of unique key values generated by this script so that I can display their values for example? I don't want to display the values created by the caller batch program, I only want to identify the key values created in the current batch script so that I can traverse their values and possibly print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[untested]

Before

```
FOR /f "usebackq…
```

put

```
set "keynameslist="
```

Then
…SET /a count_%%b=0)

becomes

```
…SET /a count_%%b=0&set "keynameslist=!keynameslist! %%b")
```

result in `keynameslist` is space-separated list of keynames with leading space.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks a lot! I'll test it and update you.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you again.

Comment: This is a new question which is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77575331/4180447