# How to write a function in batch script that will parse text file to load variable values and return the result to the caller

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, scope

Per this question:

[How to identify the list of unique variable names that are parsed from text file using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77568086/4180447)

I managed to write batch script that will load the variable values and array variable values from a text file by parsing it.

Now, I want to do this in a function or another batch script which will be called by the main script. For example:

```
:: this is the main Windows Batch Script
call LoadConfigValues.bat
:: display the loaded vales
set
```

I noticed that since the script being called `LoadConfigValues.bat` has the statement `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` then all the variables generated by this script will be removed.

How I can force the new variables created by the script `LoadConfigValues.bat` will be available to the main script?

Comment: Would you be able to have the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command in the parent script instead?

Comment: If this is the only solution, then so be it. This means I must pass a flag to the child script to tell if it is needed to execute the `setlocal` statement.

Comment: Take a look at [Make an environment variable survive ENDLOCAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262287/make-an-environment-variable-survive-endlocal/8254331#8254331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: (the dark one's suggestion)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call subroutine
rem your variables available here
```

in the subroutine:

```
if "" neq "!!" setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

so that the `setlocal` in the subroutine is only invoked if it it not already in effect (BUT - the variables changed/created would be backed out by the implicit `endlocal` at the end of the subroutine script).

Solution 2:

```
call subroutine "filename"
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e in ("filename") do set "%%e"
del "filename"
```

in the subroutine:

```
if "%~1" neq "" for %%e in (%keynameslist%) do set %%e>>"%~1"
```

to write the variablenames that start with the entries in `keynameslist` to the file `%1` and their values in the format `var=value` if `%1` is specified.

[both untested]