# How to parse JVM Command Line to add additional switches using Windows Batch Script

Tags: windows, parsing, jvm-arguments

With the help of @Magoo in a previous question, I could write a batch script to parse text files with key/value pairs and load the keys as environment variables. Following is the script:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem This script ready text file and parses key/value pairs and loads the keys and their values as environment variables

SET "configfile=.\testconfigfile.txt"

:: remove variables starting count_
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set count_ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%b IN ("%configfile%") DO (
 IF "%%c" neq "" (
  set keyname=%%b
  echo Key Name = !keyname!
  if "!keyname:~-4!"=="_arr" (
    IF DEFINED count_%%b (SET /a count_%%b+=1) ELSE (SET /a count_%%b=0)
    SET "!keyname![!count_%%b!]=%%c"
  ) else (
    SET "!keyname!=%%c"
  )
 )
)
SET count
SET |FIND "["
SET do_
SET delete_

GOTO :EOF
```

Now I have a batch script `apply_jvm_changes.bat` that must parse the Java command line used to launch a Java Program and add additional JVM switches.

The batch script to be updated looks like the following:

```
%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe -Xbootclasspath/p:path1;path2; -classpath path1;path2; -Dswitch1 -Dswitch2 -Dhttps.protocol="TLSv1.2" -Dswitch3 -DswitchN com.main.class pram1 pram2 pramN
```

I want to parse the file and update it by adding `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path\to\cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`  to look like the following:

```
%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe -Xbootclasspath/p:path1;path2; -classpath path1;path2; -Dswitch1 -Dswitch2 -Dhttps.protocol="TLSv1.2" -Dswitch3 -DswitchN -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path\to\cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit com.main.class pram1 pram2 pramN
```

Note that the addition need to be inserted before `com.main.class pram1 pram2 pramN` part in the above command line.

I am trying to figure out how to do that using batch script or other tool I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "jre_home=wherever"

SET "original=%%JRE_HOME%%\bin\java.exe -Xbootclasspath/p:path1;path2; -classpath path1;path2; -Dswitch1 -Dswitch2 -Dhttps.protocol="TLSv1.2" -Dswitch3 -DswitchN com.main.class"
SET "addition=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path\to\cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

SET "before=com.main.class"

:: FOR %%e IN (%original%) DO SET "before=%%e"
CALL SET "finalxxx=%%original:%before%=%addition% %before%%%"

SET original
SET finalxxx

GOTO :EOF
```

Not enough information to provide a proper answer - I've made a number of assumptions.

First, I don't have a variable `jre_home`, so I simply assigned one.

Next, there's no indication of whether the strings are fixed or may contain `poison characters` (those characters with special meaning to batch which may cause unexpected results.) `%` is one of those characters. In order to preserve the `%` in the `original` value, it needs to be "escaped" by an additional `%`.

There's no indication of what the formula is for the insert-point. I've assumed that the new string is to be inserted before the last token of the `original` string.

So - locate the last string (assumed to be unique) as `before`, then replace that string with addition+thestring. This uses the `call set "var1=%%var2:%string1%=%string2%%%"` syntax. To make this a little more obvious, the elements involved are `call set "var1=%%var2: %string1% = %string2% %%"` which executes `set "var1=%var2: string1 = string2 %"` in a subshell.

Then show `original` and `finalxxx` - using variable-names with the same length makes them easier to compare.

Since it now appears that the insertion point is before the unique constant string `com.main.class`, `before` is known hence it can simply be `set`. I've commented-out the original establishment of `before` to allow the narrative to make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. In your logic, you are replacing the last token (space separated) with the addition and the last token itself. I have updated the question. I need to replace the last fixed part `com.main.class pram1 pram2 pramN` which is fixed, with the `addition + the last part`. I will think about this, and if you can modify the answer accordingly it will be great.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have provided my updates. I will create a new question for writing the script to update the batch script and will attempt to write the script.

Comment: This is the final part where I need help with. I hope you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78214458/4180447